# How to create optional fields in model when making a djangorestapi in python?

Tags: python-3.x, api, sqlite, django-models, django-rest-framework

```
class IbaseEntity(models.Model):
    usrStatus = models.BooleanField()
    createdTime = models.DateTimeField()
    createdUserID = models.IntegerField(max_length=20)
    updateTime = models.DateTimeField()
    updateUserID = models.IntegerField(max_length=20)

class employee(IbaseEntity, models.Model):
    emp_id = models.IntegerField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    emp_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    emp_surname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.emp_name
```

i want all date time fields to be optional how can I do that ?

Comment: set [**`null=True`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#null) in your model field

Comment: doesn't work still can't create table entries without those fields

Comment: set `null=True` should work after you migrate those chances to your database. try `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`. Depending on your python version you can use `python3 manage....`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```